# How to read uint256[] array from a method in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm using this function in my smart contract. It returns an uint256[] array containing the tokens that the user owns.

```
 /**
   * @dev Returns all of the tokens that the user owns
   * @return An array of token indices
   */
  function myTokens()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint256[]
    )
  {
    return ownedTokens[msg.sender];
  }
```

In my web3 js console log, I get the below.

[image]

How do I read that array in my js code? Honestly, I don't understand the entire array. I just want to get the token IDs, which it supposed to return.

I'm expecting something like below as shown in Remix.

[image]

Here's my web3 js code.

```
async function retrieveTokenId(contract, walletAddress) {

  await contract.methods.myTokens().call(function(err, res){
        if(!err){
            console.log(res);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: can you add the web3 code you used to get the console log?

Comment: I've added the web3 code. I used the exactly the same code for another method call "contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call(function(err,res){......" and it works fine. That method returns an unit256, not an array.

Comment: if you are using async await, you do not have to pass callbacks. Also the call returns your array.

Comment: Sorry @SanjaySB I don't understand. I'm new to all this. You mean I should remove "async" and "await" from the function above?

Comment: Try 

`const array = await contract.methods.myTokens().call({ from: account });`
array will have your array

Comment: I tried, and I got error "Error: Provided address "[object Object]" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address"

Comment: I also tried "const array = await contract.methods.myTokens().call(function(err, res){...." and I still received the same gibberish array in my console.log for array.

Comment: `account` was a variable. You have to pass actual account address.

Comment: Try console.log(array). Remove the callback.

Comment: Did the above. It still returns the same ugly looking array.

Comment: Can you please post the "ugly looking array" and explain how exactly it is different from your desired output?

Comment: You have compiled and deployed the contract. Right? The log looks like it is displaying an object and not the array.

Comment: @goodvibration I've posted the array above, or rather the object as Sanjay pointed out. Well, I was hoping to get an array of token Ids as I saw on Remix (shown above).

Comment: @SanjaySB Yes, I even showed the output I got from Remix above. It's running on Ropsten network now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my own problem with the help of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/53608/sanjay-s-b. To display the array, I just need to do the below in my js code.

```
async function retrieveTokenId(contract, walletAddress) {

    const array = await contract.methods.myTokens().call({
        from: walletAddress
    });

    for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i]);
    }

    output = JSON.stringify(array, null, 4);
    console.log(output);

}
```

I could either use a for loop or a JSON.stringify to display the array. Read all about it here, https://medium.com/@timothyrobards/understanding-json-in-javascript-5098876d0915

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

You can check it [here](https://heliowallet.com/interact-and-deploy-contracts):

Contract address: 0xc0adf1ccc703a0a3393892600883a1a91a4e38de

Method: getRecentActivity

[image]

```
        let outputsDisplay = [];
        let outputs = await this.state.contract.methods[this.state.contractABI.name].apply(null, this.state.inputs).call();
        if (this.state.contractABI.outputs.length === 1) {
            outputsDisplay.push(outputs !== null ? outputs.toString() : '');
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.functionSelected.outputs.length; i++) {
                outputsDisplay.push(outputs[i] !== null ? outputs[i].toString() : '');
            }
        }
        console.log(outputsDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3(<RPC provider>)

async function retrieveTokenId(abi, address) {
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)
    let value=await contract.methods.myTokens().call()
    console.log(value)
    return value
}
```